# How to strecth background images behind max-width content divs

Tags: html, css, background

What is the correct way to have header and footer backgrounds that stretch out to fill the broswer window no matter how big the viewport is stretched to while having the main content (header, content and footer) only stretch to a max-length like http://moz.com

I tried using the background shortcut with 3 seperate images positioned and repeat-x but is there a better way?

Comment: Questions must show a minimal level of effort. Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried a background-size property?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Stefan Dunn's comment, try `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Josh, Stefan and Ty. Not sure how I would impliment background-sizeJust add it for each and set to 100%?

Is the below method a clumbsy workaround to a layout that has a standard method?

```
<header>
<div id="header-content">
.......
</div>
</header>

<section> <!-- This is the main content area for each page -->
<div id="main-page-content">
........
</div>
</section>

<footer>
<div id="footer-content">
........
</div>
</footer>




header {
width: 100%
background: url(images/headerbg.png) center repeat-x;
}

#header-content {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px;
}


section {
width: 100%
background: url(images/main-contentbg.png) center repeat-x;
}

#main-page-content {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px;
}


footer {
width: 100%
background: url(images/footerbg.png) center repeat-x;
}

#footer-content {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Add `background-size: cover;` to the `header { }` selector and the `footer { }` selector